# What is the lmer/nlme equivalent of the REPEATED subcommand in SPSS's MIXED procedure?

Tags: r, spss, lme4, mixed-models, nlme

I came across an SPSS syntax like this

```
MIXED value BY factor1
    /CRITERIA=CIN(95) MXITER(100) MXSTEP(10) SCORING(1) SINGULAR(0.000000000001)
    HCONVERGE(0, ABSOLUTE) LCONVERGE(0, ABSOLUTE) PCONVERGE(0.000001,
    ABSOLUTE)
    /FIXED=factor1 | SSTYPE(3)
    /METHOD=REML
    /REPEATED=factor1 | SUBJECT(participant) COVTYPE(UN).
```

and struggle to find an equivalent `lmer`/`nlme` (or R in general) formulation for this kind of models.

Does anybody know how to convert the `REPEATED` subcommand into R code?

Comment: This might be better suited to CrossValidated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This summarizes the [answers](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2018q1/thread.html#26557) I got on the r-sig-mixed-models mailing list:
The `REPEATED` command specifies the structure in the residual variance-covariance matrix (**R** matrix), the so-called **R-side** structure, of the [model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model). For `lme4::lmer()` this structure is fixed to a multiple of the identity matrix. However, one can specify the **R-side** structure using the `weights` and `correlation` arguments in `nlme::gls()` as follows:

```
gls(value ~ factor1,
    correlation = corSymm(form = ~ 1|participant),
    weights = varIdent(form = ~1|factor1),
    method = "REML", 
    data = data)
```

If one needs **G-side** effects in addition to the R-side structure, `nlme::lme()` provides the appropriate extensions.

Answer (score 1):

We have run some mixed models in a paper where we replicated all SPSS-results in R. This was our syntax:

```
MIXED y BY x1 WITH x2 x3
  /CRITERIA=CIN(95) MXITER(100) MXSTEP(10) SCORING(1) SINGULAR(0.000000000001) HCONVERGE(0, 
    ABSOLUTE) LCONVERGE(0, ABSOLUTE) PCONVERGE(0.000001, ABSOLUTE)
  /FIXED=x1 x2 x3 | SSTYPE(3)
  /METHOD=REML
  /PRINT=G  R SOLUTION TESTCOV
  /RANDOM=INTERCEPT x1 | SUBJECT(id) COVTYPE(UN)
  /REPEATED=x1| SUBJECT(id) COVTYPE(UN).


lmer(
  y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (1 + x1 | id),
  data = data,
  # this one is required because the random slope
  # is categorical. else, you could model uncorrelated
  # slope / intercept, see below 
  control = lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore")
)
```

or

```
lmer(
  y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (1 + x1 || id),
  data = data
)
```

We have converted our time-variable `x1` to a factor, because it seemed like SPSS cannot deal with numeric time-variables in the `REPEATED`-statement.

To get the same standard errors, p-values and confidence intervals, use `lmerTest::summary(..., ddf = "Satterthwaite")`, because SPSS uses Satterthwaite-approximation as default.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `/REPEATED` is just the way to specify random effects, so

`random=~factor1|participant` in nlme.

I'm also guessing that the intercept in both the fixed and the random effects is implicit.

So in lme4 + lmerTest the whole model might be:

```
m <- lmerTest::lmer(value ~ 1 + factor1 + (1+factor1|participant))
lmerTest::anova(m, type=3,ddf='Satterthwaite')
```

Comment: The `REPEATED` command specifies the R-side structure (see my A), so your model formulation is, at least in the general case, not equivalent to the model implied by the SPSS syntax.